# Getting the name and the code of an icon using regex

Tags: regex

I'm currently looking for a way to get the name and the code of the icons using an regex

```
.hif-glyph:before { content: '\e800'; } /* '' */
.hif-glyph-1:before { content: '\e801'; } /* '' */
.hif-glyph-2:before { content: '\e802'; } /* '' */
```

The name was no problem: `.(.*)(?=:before { content: )`

This would match `.hif-glyph-N` without `:before { content:`. but no i need the add the `'\e800'` without: `; } /* '' */` and after matching this i need to combine that thing and do it with one regex... but i really can't figure it out at the moment.

http://regexr.com/39r58

Update:

I can now also find the name: with: `'\\e(\d*|\w*)'` but i cant figure it out how to combine these to regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, hope it'll help.

```
.(.*)(?::before { content: )(.*)(?:;.*)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it will match the whole line but we can always separate what you want by using capturing groups (..). Probably I misunderstood your expectation for this problem :)

Comment: Had to give you the top answered point - you were the first one who got it right for my need. :) just didn't know the thing with the capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, got that going easier than i thought - after testing and testing - reading the cheatsheet of regexr...

```
(([^\.]+?)(?=:before { content: )|'\\e(\d*|\w*)')
```

to match the parts I need.

http://regexr.com/39r5e

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regular expression based off your desired output.

```
([^.:]+):[^']+'([^']+)'
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oD4qE3/3)

Comment: This would also match ´:before { content: ´

Comment: Yes it would but it's not a big deal because the match results you want are in the capturing groups `( ... )`

Comment: I always thought that the matches i want to get should be the final match. what do you mean with the capturing group?

Comment: AH i got it & it also works with my other test values :) - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
\.([^:]+):[^']+'([^']+)
```

Explanation:

```
\.       # match a period
([^:]+)  # capture everything not a colon :
:        # match colon
[^']+'   # match everything up to single quote
([^']+)  # capture everything that is not a single quote, i.e., everything between the quotes
```

Comment: This also would match    
This would also match ':before { content: ' ... I tried this on regexr.com

Comment: But the text you want is in the capture groups.